# Expect Script : spawn id exp4 not open

Tags: terminal, sftp, expect

I have created an expect script to download some files via sftp.

I now need to copy the files so I have the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set now [clock seconds]
set date [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y-%m-%d}]


spawn sftp test@user
expect "sftp>"
send "cd public_html\n";
expect "sftp>"
send "get *\n";
expect "sftp>"
send "quit\n";
expect " $"
send "cp -R /media/user/A/$date /media/user/B\n"
```

But I am getting the error:

```
sftp> quit
send: spawn id exp4 not open
while executing
"send "cp -R /media/user/A/$date /media/user/B\n""
    (file "./test1" line 44)
```

What is causing this?

Comment: `send` and `expect` are all talking to the spawned program. after you `send quit\n` the spawned `sftp` would exit and you cannot `send` to it any more. if you want to run commands on your local server you can use [exec](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.html).

Comment: That's a good point. I'd suggest you `expect eof` after you `send quit`